# CSP error while integrating powerBI to angular

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, powerbi

I'm getting this error while adding powerBi report to my angular application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32QYY.jpg)

I tried with this below code (NOTE it was replaced with actual token and URL)

```
const accessToken = "token"
const orginalUrl ="url"
const embedReportId = "id";
const config = {
  type: 'report',
  id: embedReportId,
  embedUrl: orginalUrl,
  tokenType: pbi.models.TokenType.Aad,
  accessToken: accessToken
};
let reportContainer = this.reportContainer.nativeElement;
let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(
  pbi.factories.hpmFactory,
  pbi.factories.wpmpFactory,
  pbi.factories.routerFactory
);
let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);

report.off('loaded');
report.on('loaded', () => {
  console.log('Loaded');
});
report.on('error', (er: any) => {
  console.log('Error', er);
});
```

Comment: What are the existing CSP headers that your app defines? Looks like you need to add the microsoft, outlook and powerbi domains to the frame-src and frame-ancestor directives: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you